# Installing older version of osm2pgsql

Tags: osm2pgsql

I am trying to use open source project named SciGRID to construct a power network. The project requires power tag data to be filtered (using osmosis) and loaded into a postgres database using osm2pgsql. I have currently managed to get osm2pgsql version 0.92 installed in my system. However the tables created by the new version (0.92) is not in line with tables required by SciGRID. They specify the table osm_planet_nodes table (created by osm2pgsql and .style file when loading filtered power data)  to contain a tag column, which it doesnt (contains only id, lat and lon). According to the following post,

[Column "tags" is missing in PostgreSQL table created with osm2pgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292860/column-tags-is-missing-in-postgresql-table-created-with-osm2pgsql)

the new version of osm2pgsql is likely creating some additional tables with potentially these information (separated into 3 or 4 columns). However my main goal is to get tables created by osm2pgsql to work with SciGRID, which require the tags column to be present in the planet_osm_nodes table.
I am therefore wondering if there is a way get osm2pgsql version 0.82 (requested by SciGRID) installed in my system. I am using ubuntu 18.04 and have osm2pgsql 0.92 installed.

Comment: Use option `--hstore-all` in the command line import of current `osm2pgsql` PS: did not try so you'd better test with small area to see if output is what you expect. More options worth to look at https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/osm2pgsql.md

Comment: This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306616/where-to-find-windows-osm2psql-binaries-in-2018) is relevant ... but unfortunately it describes how to get access to 6 month olds build at most. The remaining alternative is to fetch the code for the specific version from github and to compile it yourself. (I leave this as a comment and not an answer in case someone knows a repository with compiled code)

Comment: Alternatively, but it is more a hack than anything else, is to create a view / table that aggregates the data with the columns your app needs.