# Nodes returned by OSRM map match service not found in the PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine, nodes, map-matching

The call to [OSRM map matching](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.620048,46.99917?overview=simplified&generate_hints=false&annotations=nodes&radiuses=50;50&geometries=geojson) returns a list of `nodes`:

> {"code":"Ok","matchings":[{"confidence":0.000854076,"geometry":{"coordinates":[[8.610984,46.998978],[8.61309,47.000206],[8.613144,47.000283],[8.613134,47.000372],[8.613506,47.000469],[8.613833,47.000622],[8.615571,47.001608],[8.616024,47.0013],[8.616167,47.000626],[8.616434,47.000464],[8.616554,47.000444],[8.617017,47.000525],[8.617696,47.000288],[8.620298,46.999676]],"type":"LineString"},"legs":[{"steps":[],"summary":"","weight":117.6,"duration":117.6,"annotation":{"nodes":[384845483,3831831361,2628299968,502266756,346268605,373873712,1302513709,9444444740,2431858827,10287564212,271979126,10721097610,10287564276,10721097609,10721097608,7328319500,7328319511,10287564277,271979123,9441944872,271979114,4560271019,373878694,4560271018,373878690,9442435560,373878688,9053978499,9442435552,9442435679,373878684,1085916739,373880925,9442435755,1085916895,373880928,1085916901,373880931,5753185380,373880934,4244175765,2431858826,433073515,373880937]},"distance":927.4}],"weight_name":"routability","weight":117.6,"duration":117.6,"distance":927.4}],"tracepoints":[{"alternatives_count":0,"waypoint_index":0,"matchings_index":0,"distance":74.351292817,"name":"Alte Kantonsstrasse","location":[8.610984,46.998978]},{"alternatives_count":5,"waypoint_index":1,"matchings_index":0,"distance":59.381641586,"name":"Schönenbuchstrasse","location":[8.620298,46.999676]}]}

When I copy that list of numeric ids and pass it to the postgis/postgis Docker installation
with germany-latest.osm.pbf loaded at my notebook, then nothing is found:

[image: PostGIS screenshot]

> SELECT * FROM planet_osm_point WHERE osm_id in (384845483,3831831361,2628299968,502266756,346268605,373873712,1302513709,9444444740,2431858827,10287564212,271979126,10721097610,10287564276,10721097609,10721097608,7328319500,7328319511,10287564277,271979123,9441944872,271979114,4560271019,373878694,4560271018,373878690,9442435560,373878688,9053978499,9442435552,9442435679,373878684,1085916739,373880925,9442435755,1085916895,373880928,1085916901,373880931,5753185380,373880934,4244175765,2431858826,433073515,373880937);

But when I try to look up the node ids manually in [the OSM browser](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/384845483), they are found:

[image: OSM browser screenshot]

Am I referencing a wrong column? Is `osm_id` in `planet_osm_point` not the node id?

My long term target is to retrieve the list of way ids, when given the list of node ids by the OSRM map matching service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong table. To obtain the node information you are looking for, you should be using the `planet_osm_node` table. Read more [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133149/planet-osm-point-versus-planet-osm-nodes-for-querying-places).